# Java8 way to handle if..else check in Collections

Tags: java, java-8

Below one is my code and I would like to write a better equivalent code in Java8

```
    List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("Apple","Orange","Banana");
    List<String> animals = Arrays.asList("Tiger","Lion","Monkey");
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    Map<String,List<String>> allLists = new HashMap() {{
        put("fruits",fruits);
        put("animals",animals);
    }};
```

Legacy prior Java8 way of checking

```
    if(allLists.get("fruits")!=null) {
        List<String> fruits1 = allLists.get("fruits");
        if(fruits1.contains("Apple")) {
            System.out.println("Apple is there");
        }
    }
```

Java8 Way of doing..

```
    Consumer<List<String>> consumer1 = arg ->{
        Optional.of(arg.contains("Apple")).filter(value -> value.equals(true)).ifPresent(value1 -> System.out.println("Apple is available"));
    };
    Optional.of(allLists.get("fruits")).ifPresent(consumer1);
```

Currently the Java8 way is returning the output "Apple is available"..

Question is, How do I handle if Apple is not in the ArrayList...
Ex: If Apple is not in the list , I want to print "Apple is not Available"

Please suggest me better approaches to handle both cases.

Comment: That's the most convoluted use of Optional I've ever seen. What's wrong with the initial version?

Comment: You better first define what "better" means for you. Just because lambdas and streams exist doesn't mean you have to use them for everything.

Comment: @shmosel, in my method there are multiple if..else checks. I foresee some cyglometric complexity error will appeared on unit testing tools. Moving checks in different methods is one possible solution but before that thought of using Java8 things on this case. any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for getOrDefault on the map, like this:

```
if(allLists.getOrDefault("fruits", Collections.emptyList()).contains("Apple"))
    System.out.println("Having apples");
```

Basically, this eliminates the key-not-present check you normally do. In situations, where you want to continue to work with the list (grouping in maps), you may also check out `computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 0):

First, `Optional.of` will throw a NullPointerException if you pass null to it. You need to use `ofNullable` here as

```
Optional.ofNullable(allLists.get("fruits"))
```

Optional in Java 8 does not have a method that can be executed if a value is not found.

But Java-9 has [ifPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) that takes a Runnable where you can print that Apple is not there

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Optional is not replacement for null. Cleverly use of Optional in place of null and simple if...else checks is bad idea.

Why Optional: Optional's are created to handle value/no values(empty) cases on Streams. Optional's are created to avoid breaking stream methods for null check during fluent chaining.

Until you have a valid reason to create Optional, do not create it.

ex: The below is not a good Idea,

```
String process(String s) {
return Optional.ofNullable(s).orElseGet(this::getDefault);
}
```

//Better way is

```
String process(String s) {
return s!=null ? s : getDefault();
}
```

PITFALLS: Optional.get is a really attractive method to use but beware that Optional.get throws "NoSuchElementException". Not similar to get method in java Collections ( they wont throw exception if the value does not present).
So use get method along with isPresent() method.

Places you should not use Optional:

- Do not create Optional type Fields
- Do not use Optional Parameters (forcing someone to create empty
  optional instead of passing null is really bad)
- Do not combine Java collections with Optional.